# PHP Hyperlink/Pop-up table

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, html-table, popup

I'm creating a PHP table from MySQL query as follows :

```
    $resultkulim = mysql_query("SELECT customer_name, zone_name, segment_code, COUNT(segment_code) FROM complete_wk where zone_name = 'ZONE KULIM' and (segment_code = 's30' or segment_code='s40' or segment_code='s50'')");
    $totalrrkulim = mysql_query("SELECT zone_name, repeat_rc, COUNT(repeat_rc) FROM complete_wk where zone_name = 'ZONE KULIM' and repeat_rc>1 and (segment_code = 's30' or segment_code='s40' or segment_code='s50')");

                echo "<table class='table1'>";
                echo "<thead>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<th>Zone</th>";
                        echo "<th>Total TR</th>";
                        echo "<th>Total RR (RR>1)</th>";
                        echo "<th>%RR</th>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                echo "</thead>";
                //kulim row
                while($rowkulim = mysql_fetch_array($resultkulim))
                  {
                        echo "<tbody>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>Zone Kulim</td>";
                            echo "<td >" . $rowkulim['COUNT(segment_code)'] . "</td>";
                      while($rrkulim = mysql_fetch_array($totalrrkulim))
                          {
                            $myresultkulim = $rrkulim['COUNT(repeat_rc)'] / $rowkulim['COUNT(segment_code)'] * 100;
                                  echo "<td>" . $rrkulim['COUNT(repeat_rc)'] . "</td>";
                                  echo "<td>" . number_format($myresultkulim) . "%" . "</td>";
                              echo "</tr>"; 
                            echo "</tbody>";
                          }
                  }
                echo "</table>";
```

And the example result of the table is as follow :

```
Zone         Total TR    Total RR    %RR
Zone Kulim     182          11        6%
```

What I want to do is, I want to be able to click at the result of Total TR, which is "182" and it will bring me to other page which contains the table of details of that 182 result.

I've already done the other table and it is located at "localhost/tmj/index.php/tr/kulim"

I hope somebody can enlighten me on how to either make a popup window or hyperlink to the other pages from the table code above.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this is what you want,
try

```
echo '<td ><a href="index.php/tr/kulim">' . $rowkulim['COUNT(segment_code)'] . "</a></td>";
```

or is this a dynamic link?